# Exponential double integral after use of Fourier transform

Tags: integration, exponential-function, fourier-transform

I'm unable to understand the steps between eq. 16 and 17 in Gaarde, M. B. et al. Phys. Rev. A - At. Mol. Opt. Phys. 83, (2011):

[image]

$\tilde{f}(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ and their convention is: $f(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde{f}(\omega)~e^{-i w t} dt$  and $\tilde{f}(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)~e^{i w t} d\omega$

What I have so far:
$$
\Delta E= \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}z(t) \frac{\partial E}{\partial t} \text{dt} \text{ | insert FT}\\
= \frac{1}{2\pi}\iint^{\infty}_{-\infty} \tilde{z}(\omega)~\tilde{E}(\omega) \frac{\partial }{\partial t} \left(~e^{-i 2 \omega t} \right)\text{d}\omega~\text{dt} \text{ | do partial deriv.} \\
= - \frac{i}{\pi}\iint^{\infty}_{-\infty} \omega~\tilde{z}(\omega)~\tilde{E}(\omega)~e^{-i 2 \omega t} \text{d}\omega~\text{dt}
$$
Now, I guess due the symmetry of z and E, I can do this, however I am unsure:
$$
= - \frac{i}{\pi}\iint^{\infty}_{0}\omega~2~\tilde{z}(\omega)~\tilde{E}(\omega)~e^{-i 2 \omega t} \text{d}\omega~\text{dt}
$$
Then, I could do the integration w.r.t. t, but then I end up with:
$$
= \frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\infty}_{0} \tilde{z}(\omega)~\tilde{E}(\omega) \text{d}\omega
$$

Where is the imag coming from? And why is the $2\omega$ still in eq. 17?

I did my best, but - obviously - I'm not an expert.. sry. any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your mistake is that the FT of a product is a convolution, so that $\mathcal{F}( z{\partial E \over \partial t}) = \mathcal{F} z * \mathcal{F} {\partial E \over\partial t}  $